# Counting consecutive instances in arrays

Tags: python

My code currently returns a row of a CSV file with `print(line)`:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'B']
```

I'd like to count the consecutive instances of zero giving me the largest amount of free space in a single block for that row (seat booking system project). I'd also like to count the amount of zeroes giving me two values - the largest block of zeroes and the total amount of zeroes in the list. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can the strings be longer than 1 symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby()` to group by runs of zeros:

```
from itertools import groupby

max_run = 0
totalcount = line.count('0')
if totalcount:
    max_run = max(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(line) if k == '0')
```

The `if` is needed because if there are no `'0'` values in the line, `max()` throws an exception complaining about an empty sequence.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> line = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'B']
>>> line.count('0')
9
>>> max(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(line) if k == '0')
8
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lis = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'B']
```

Total count:

```
>>> lis.count('0')
9
```

Max consecutive zeroes:

```
>>> max(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(lis) if k=='0')
8
```